# Importing Contributions - Data errors

Tags: contributions, data-import

Hope you are all keeping well in this strange times!

We are currently trying to import some contributions in into the system from a CSV file (updating) but can't get past an error that is coming up. The error is coming up for all the records we are trying to import - Invalid value for field(s) : field ID;

Currently we are mapping the contacts External ID number to Contribution ID when running the import so could this be causing the problem.
As these contributions are new contributions (to existing donors with the system) why does contribution ID / Invoice ID / Transaction ID need to be a required field.
Currently the csv only only contains the External ID as the URN.

Any held would really be appreciated.

Many thanks
Terry

Comment: I think if they are new contributions you should use 'Insert new contributions' for the import mode rather than 'Update'. But I may have misunderstood your 'from a CSV file (updating)'.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The contributions are "new" as such, but are from existing donors / contributors that are already held in the system. Hope that makes sense. Should these be classed as new in the import, rather than updating? Many thanks, Terry

Comment: Yes, as the 'update' would refer to an existing contribution you are updating, rather than a contact.  So for new contribution there's no 'contribution id' in the system

Comment: Thanks Rebecca thats great, all sorted now :)

Comment: Great. Glad it's working now.